# content_tag not working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to set content_tag's class or height it gives me a view with a hash inside the content tag.

```
  def book_obj(book)
    content_tag :div, height: 50, class: "something"
  end

- @books.each do |book|
  = book_obj(book)
```

In the view:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <div>{:height=&gt;50, :class=&gt;"something"}</div>
    <div>{:height=&gt;50, :class=&gt;"something"}</div>
    <div>{:height=&gt;50, :class=&gt;"something"}</div>
</div>
```

I think it should work like `<div class="something"></div>.`
How to use this method properly?

Comment: `content_tag :div, height: 50, class: "something"` means `content_tag :div, {height: 50, class: "something"}` Calling `to_s` on the hash produces that stuff. So simply change it to: `content_tag :div, nil, {height: 50, class: "something"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `content_tag` requires a content argument.

```
content_tag :div, "Content", height: 50, class: "something"
```

[See the Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

Answer (score 1):

By checking the docs for the method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

The second argument is the content for the element.